# Can a water flow in a pipe be non-turbulent with a Reynolds number greater than 2000?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, bernoulli-equation

I have a venturi tube with a narrowing in the middle with 4 manometric tubes and 2 others in the wide part, at the beginning and at the end. I can clearly see that the pressure is no longer conserved in the last middle tube . So far so good because the velocity is clearly higher so the Reynolds number should go up and it will have become a turbulent fluid.

My problem is that when I calculate the number of Reynolds, at the point of the first tube that is at the beginning in the wide part has a Reynolds number of 7000, then it would be a turbulent fluid from the beginning and the pressure would not be conserved.
Can the number of Reynolds from which a fluid becomes turbulent vary? Or is it simply that the fluid takes a distance to become turbulent?

[image: Measures]
These are the measures that I've taken, the first column is the number of the tube, the second the diameter of the Venturi pipe in each tube and the third is the area of the pipe in each tube. h(cm) is the static pressure and v^2/2g the dynamic pressure, $h_s$ is the  sum of both and $h_t$ is the total pressure measured by an hypodermic probe.

[image: Reynold number]

This is the table with Reynolds number of each tube.

As you can see the Reynolds number is greater than 2000 even in the first tube, so its a turbulent flow. I have done a little estimation with Darcy - Weisbach equation and the results are more or less in agreement with those obtained experimentally). So could it be a turbulent flow and do not lose a lot of pressure in the first section?

Thanks

Comment: A little schematic would not go amiss here. Also, details of the $\text{Re}$ calculation would help us exclude a computation error, somewhere.

Comment: I have edited right now with the details!